# how to duplicate audio channel in stereo audio in video with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I just got a lot of video files. They all have stereo audio track - left channel and right channel. But actually, the right channel is blank, is empty. When you play this video with stereo earphones, only left side earphone has sound, no sound come from the right side earphone. So is there a way to duplicate this left channel and make it become the right channel, so that both sides of earphone has sound? I know I can do this in some video editing software, but they are expensive and too much system resource wasted. Can i do this in FFmpeg?

Comment: yes [start here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

Comment: @kesh ,this page doesn't help.

Answer (score 7):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -af "pan=stereo|FL=FL|FR=FL" out.mp4
```

This should work. Since your right channel is blank, setting `FL=FL|FR=FL` means front left of input mapping to front left of output, and front left of input mapping to front right of output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).